# Rearrangement of Grignard reagent formed from exocycloproyl vinyl bromide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, grignard-reagent

> [image]

First, I prepared the grignard reagent then performed nucleophilic addition to the carbonyl carbon  and then did hydrolysis.

So basically in my product, $\ce{-Br}$ is replaced by $\ce{-CH2OH}$

But answer given is:

[image]

Why is my mechanism wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grignard reagents are capable of rearranging, especially in this situation where there is significant strain. The specific vinyl bromide you drew here has been studied: [*J. Org. Chem.,* **1974,** *39* (10), pp 1411–1416](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00926a020). The table of data shown below is hard to read without including more of the text, but it was found that at 66 C in THF, after 5-10 minutes, 41% of the initial Grignard had undergone rearrangement, so this is a fairly likely process.

[image]

[image]

A potential mechanism for the rearrangement is:
[image]